# Eleventy (11ty) + Vite, inserts import into js file, but does not generate the imported file

Tags: javascript, vite, rollupjs, eleventy

I'm using 11ty with the eleventy-plugin-vite plugin to use Vite in post processing. However, when generating the production build, a script tag is inserted into the .html files with an src attribute pointing to a file that does not exist. The same happens in the generated .js file, an import for this file that does not exist is added right at the beginning of the generated code. This causes an error in the js file which cannot be interpreted by the browser. I'm not very familiar with rollup yet and I'm getting to know 11ty now, it could be a configuration error, I appreciate any guidance.

.eleventy.js

```
const markdownItAnchor = require('markdown-it-anchor')

const EleventyPluginNavigation = require('@11ty/eleventy-navigation')
const EleventyPluginRss = require('@11ty/eleventy-plugin-rss')
const EleventyVitePlugin = require('@11ty/eleventy-plugin-vite')

const rollupPluginCritical = require('rollup-plugin-critical').default

const filters = require('./utils/filters.js')
const transforms = require('./utils/transforms.js')
const shortcodes = require('./utils/shortcodes.js')

const { resolve } = require('path')

module.exports = function (eleventyConfig) {
    eleventyConfig.setServerPassthroughCopyBehavior('copy')
    eleventyConfig.addPassthroughCopy('public')

    // Plugins
    eleventyConfig.addPlugin(EleventyPluginNavigation)
    eleventyConfig.addPlugin(EleventyPluginRss)
    eleventyConfig.addPlugin(EleventyVitePlugin, {
        tempFolderName: '.11ty-vite',

        viteOptions: {
            publicDir: 'public',
            clearScreen: false,
            server: {
                mode: 'development',
                middlewareMode: true
            },
            appType: 'custom',
            assetsInclude: ['**/*.xml', '**/*.txt'],
            build: {
                mode: 'production',
                
                rollupOptions: {
                    output: {
                        assetFileNames: (assetInfo) => {
                            let extType = assetInfo.name.split('.').at(1)
                            if (/png|jpe?g|svg|gif|tiff|bmp|ico/i.test(extType)) {
                                extType = 'images'
                            }
                            return `assets/${extType}/[name]-[hash][extname]`
                        },
                        chunkFileNames: 'assets/js/[name]-[hash].js',
                        entryFileNames: 'assets/js/[name]-[hash].js'
                    },

                    plugins: [
                        rollupPluginCritical({
                            criticalUrl: './_site/',
                            criticalBase: './_site/',
                            criticalPages: [
                                { uri: 'index.html', template: 'index' }
                            ],
                            criticalConfig: {
                                inline: true
                            }
                        })
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    })

    // Filters
    Object.keys(filters).forEach((filterName) => {
        eleventyConfig.addFilter(filterName, filters[filterName])
    })

    // Transforms
    Object.keys(transforms).forEach((transformName) => {
        eleventyConfig.addTransform(transformName, transforms[transformName])
    })

    // Shortcodes
    Object.keys(shortcodes).forEach((shortcodeName) => {
        eleventyConfig.addShortcode(shortcodeName, shortcodes[shortcodeName])
    })

    let markdownLibrary = markdownIt({
        html: true,
        breaks: true,
        linkify: true
    }).use(markdownItAnchor, {
        permalink: markdownItAnchor.permalink.ariaHidden({
            placement: 'after',
            class: 'direct-link',
            symbol: '#',
            level: [1, 2, 3, 4]
        }),
        slugify: eleventyConfig.getFilter('slug')
    })
    eleventyConfig.setLibrary('md', markdownLibrary)

    // Layouts
    eleventyConfig.addLayoutAlias('base', 'base.liquid')
    eleventyConfig.addLayoutAlias('ajuda', 'ajuda.liquid')
    eleventyConfig.addLayoutAlias('error', 'error.liquid')
    eleventyConfig.addLayoutAlias('page', 'page.liquid')

    // Copy/pass-through files
    eleventyConfig.addPassthroughCopy('src/assets/css')
    eleventyConfig.addPassthroughCopy('src/assets/js')

    return {
        templateFormats: ['md', 'html', 'liquid'],
        htmlTemplateEngine: 'liquid',
        passthroughFileCopy: true,
        dir: {
            input: 'src',
            output: '_site',
            includes: '_includes',
            layouts: 'layouts',
            data: '_data'
        }
    }
}
```

structure: /

[image: project structure]

**input:**

src/assets/js/main.js

```
import Typed from 'typed.js'

var typed = new Typed('#hero .hero__questions', {
    strings: [
        'Quanto tempo e dinheiro é preciso para atingir minhas metas?',
        'Qual o real valor do meu patrimônio?',
        'Quais investimentos podem ajudar a concretizar meus sonhos?'
    ],
    typeSpeed: 30,
    loop: true,
    backSpeed: 30,
    backDelay: 5000
})

var load = this.document.getElementById('load')

window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    document.body.removeChild(load)
})
```

src/_layout/base:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
<script type="module" src="{{ '/assets/js/main.js' | url }}"></script>
...
</html>
```

**output:**

_site/index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
<script type="module" crossorigin="" src="/assets/js/index-790863bd.js"></script>
<script type="module" crossorigin="" src="/assets/js/index-076dcfdf.js"></script>
...
</html>
```

[image: generated js file]

_site/assets/js/index-076dcfdf.js
[image: generated js content]